# Receiving these errors in Future builder and Future List

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot, flutter-futurebuilder

I am facing this error, even though I have written the 'if statement'.

I also tried adding an 'else statement' like `else{return Text(" "); }` but then it completely ignores the 'if statement' and shows only the else statement in the Output, which is a Text widget.

[image]

I am also facing this error in the file 'db_helper.dart' when writing `await dbClient!.query('cart');`
[image]

Comment: a tool-tip: next time try to attach code in text form instead of code screenshots. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the first error is return something both in if and else condition like this:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
   return Expanded();
 }else{
  return Text("");
 }
```

and for the 2nd error make the code like this:

```
final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult=await dbClient!.query("cart");
```

Comment: try this and let me know if it is solving your problem or not.

Comment: The second one now gives the error "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)"

Comment: which part is causing the issue?

Comment: final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult=await dbClient!.query("cart"); this one is giving the exception  "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)"

Comment: Yes this is the value " var dbClient = await db; "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251696/discussion-between-munsif-ali-and-shahzain-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your first snippet is that you return a `Widget` only when `snapshot.hasData`, to solve this after that `return` outside of the `if` case, either `return` a `SizedBox` or a `CircularProgressIndicator` that will show loading until the `Future` yilds data.

The second snippet indicates that your return type does not match with the type of `queryResult`, so you can change the type of `queryResult` to `List<Map<String, Object?>>` and this will most probably fix all your errors.

Comment: The second snippet I changed to `List<Map<String, Object?>>` now it gives an exception on `final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult=await dbClient!.query("cart");` the exception is `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`

Comment: That error may be because of this `dbClient!` and the bang operator (!).